# Is it bad form to stage a function's steps in intermediate variables (let bindings)?

Tags: clojure

I find I tend to need intermediate variables. In Clojure that's in the form of let bindings, like `cmp-result-1` and `cmp-result-2` in the following function.

```
(defn str-cmp
    "Takes two strings and compares them. Returns the string if a match; and nil if not."
    [str-1 str-2 start-pos substr-len]

    (let [cmp-result-1 (subs str-1 start-pos substr-len)
          cmp-result-2 (subs str-2 start-pos substr-len)]
        (compare cmp-result-1 cmp-result-2)))
```

I could re-write this function without them, but to me, the function's purpose looks clearer. I tend to do this quite in a bit in my main, and that is primarily for debugging purposes, so I can pass a variable to print out intermediate output.

Is this bad form, and, if so, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nah. For arbitrary functions composed of N intermediary variables, the maximum complexity is exponential in N, if not higher. Intermediate variables most definitely allow for highly complex functions to be expressed cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

**Side note**: It's a shame that there isn't any Clojure highlighting here.

I would consider this purely a matter of preference. Never would I have considered it *bad form*. It doesn't always promote readability, but rarely does it harm it.

However, I have no idea what `rc` means, so if you're going to use auxiliary variables, they might as well promote readability by revealing some intent with a better choice of words.

Comment: Good point. I fixed the variable names.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Wouldn't `substr1, substr2` be more appropriate? Since they aren't really the result of a comparison, but the result of a substring.